# Citroen C2 Alternator

Tags: alternator, starter, stall, citroen

Please if someone could help me ill really appreciate it. I've got a Citroen C2 the Bendix of the starter was completely worn so we purchased a new starter and put it in.

At first it started. Once you put it in gear, it cuts out. After a while it just completely dies. We had someone come and look at it and he recons it's the alternator. I've been phoning around today for prices and came across a guy that said its normally the regulator on the alternator that goes? He also recons it can't be the Alternator ... any advice?

Comment: The only way the alternator could cause this is if the battery was going almost totally flat.  Is it?

Comment: What do you have to do to get it to restart?

Comment: I'd highly recommend you stay away from this "guy" first off. If the regulator is going out, it's located in the alternator, so how could it then not be the alternator which is at fault? In this case, I doubt your issue is the regulator or the alternator, but most likely something else. We really need to have you answer the above questions and probably some more before we'll be able to help you though.